# How to translate execution commands from bash script to C? or How to properly use popen() in "W" mode?

Tags: c, bash, popen, execution, freeze

Hey all. I'm trying to translate a simple bash script that executes a program (called pdb2gmx) into C commands so I can include it as a function in a much larger program, but I'm having some trouble making it happen.

The bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/local/gromacs/bin/pdb2gmx -f ${1}.pdb -o ${1}.gro -p ${1}.top << EOF
14
6
```

So what's going is that when running the program, it stops and asks for user input at two separate points, one right after the other. In the bash script, just putting down 14 and 6 seems to fulfill the input requirement, but I can't seem to pull off the same trick in C (also, I'm not really sure what the EOF is doing there, I'm just following someone else's example with that, and the script won't work without it).

This is what I have so far in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE * pdb2gmx;
    pdb2gmx = popen( "pdb2gmx -f 1BEO.pdb -o 1BEO.gro -p 1BEO.top" , "w" );
    fprintf( pdb2gmx, "EOF" );
    fprintf( pdb2gmx, "14" );
    fprintf( pdb2gmx, "6" );
    pclose( pdb2gmx );
}
```

but when this code is executed pdb2gmx just hangs at the first point where it needs user input. So what am I missing?

My sense is that the C program itself is also hanging on the execution of the `popen` line, and never getting to the `fprintf` lines, but I thought that with `popen` mode set to `"w"` you could just treat the returned stream like user input, so I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Have you tried flushing after calling fprintf?

Comment: The shell script should have `EOF` as the last line as a closing delimiter for the first `EOF`. It will work without it, but it may give a warning. You would definitely need it if there were more commands in the script following those data lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add some newlines (`\n`) to the end of those `fprintf` strings...

Comment: Wow. Never would have thought of that, but so simple. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: And you don't need the EOF. "<<EOF" is a bash construct that means "feed every line in this script until a line  with just EOF on it to the process you're starting". You implemented the same thing with popen("w").

Answer (score 1):

have you checked the value of `pdb2gmx` - do you have the path set correctly so that your program finds the pdb2gmx executable?

You might also want to call fflush()  after the fprintf()